# Redirect Url without changing browser url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have URL's that look like this:

- domain.com/web/xyz
- domain.com/web/abc
- domain.com/web/efg

All these URL's are generated on the fly, the only part that does not change is domain.com/web/

What I need is that the above URL's should be accessible via

- xyz.domain.com
- abc.domain.com
- efg.domain.com

I got this working using .htaccess , but it changes the URL from xyz.domain.com to domain.com/web/xyz which I don't want. I want the URL to remain unchanged.

Here is the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/demo_stores/%1/ [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: You cannot do cross domain redirects in an internal manner.

Comment: What you _can_ do is use a fallback host handling _all_ requests to those host names. Then instead of a redirection you do an internal rewrite, so to a _path_, not to a _url_.

Comment: sorry, but can u please explain in detail, as I am newbie in this domain, or suggest some resources , thanks

Comment: Redirecting from `xyz.domain.com` to `domain.com` is _always done as external redirection. So the browser is told to change the URL and make a fresh request. That obviously changes the visible URL in the browser. To keep the rewriting internal (inside the server) you have to stick to the same domain. So you cannot redirect to a full URL with another domain name. Instead you have to take care to internally handle the incoming request for _all_ host names (you called the "subdomains") by _one_ virtual host on the server side (_the_ host or the fallback host).